# Avoid nested subscribe call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a button, clicking it will make a service call. Finally I want to inform the  user by email. The email will be made by another service call.

```
public submitForm = (data, selected = {} ) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.service['submit'].post({body: data}).subscribe(
    () => { null },
    error => {
       console.log(error);
    };
    () => {
         // second subscribe
        this.service['email']['post']({ body: theForm.value }).subscribe(
        () = > {
           // data processing
         }
       );
     }
     );}
```

You see it is the nested subscribe. I use angular 5 and rxjs 5.5. How to avoid it?

**UPDATE:**

By the comment, I added the service code

```
public readonly service: SwaggerService
```

The actually all services are in asp.net web api, for example

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("email")]
public ActionResult postEmail([FromBody]EmailBody email)
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` to avoid nested subscription like this:

```
public submitForm = (data, selected = {} ) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.service['submit'].post({body: data})
      .switchMap(() => {
        return this.service['email']['post']({ body: theForm.value })
                  .catch(err => {
                    //handle your error here

                    //HERE YOU NEED TO DO YOUR SELF; MAKE SURE TO RETURN AN OBSERVABLE FOR HERE.
                    //I ON RXJS 6.4; So I am not sure what is `of` operator in rxjs 5.5
                    //I guss it is Observable.of
                    return Observable.of(err);
                  });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        //handle your error here

        //HERE YOU NEED TO DO YOUR SELF; MAKE SURE TO RETURN AN OBSERVABLE FOR HERE.
        //I ON RXJS 6.4; So I am not sure what is `of` operator in rxjs 5.5
        //I guss it is Observable.of
        return Observable.of(err);
      })
      .subscribe((resultOfSecondCall) => {
        //do your processing here...
        console.log(resultOfSecondCall);
      });

   }
```

Comment: So there is no error handling in the first call?

Comment: @Bigeyes If you want you can use `catch` rxjs operator to handle the error. Use `catch` operator in outer observable. Similarly, you can use `catch` operator in inner observable.

Comment: Can you update the code so I can better understand it?

Comment: @Bigeyes Updated the code. Please see the comment in code.

Comment: Actually I have one more subscription, should I use one more switchMap?

Comment: If one more api call and it depends on previous api response then yes, you can add as many switchMap as you want.

Comment: I can't find `of` operator

Comment: @Bigeyes which version of rxjs you are using? If on rxjs 5 then try import `of` like this: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way I would do it. You haven't posted any of the your `service` code, so it's hard to tell you *exactly* how to do it. I will make an assumption that your service code is doing nothing but making an `http` call to the server (and therefore returning a promise/something awaitable)

```
await this.service['submit'].post({body: data});
await this.service['email']['post']({ body: theForm.value });
```

Using `rxjs` over standard `HttpClient`/`Promises` doesn't seem to hold any benefit here. The only real requirements seems to be that you need the first call to execute (successfully) before you fire off the email. I would just do two lines of code using `await` rather than chaining some observables here.

As a side note, in order to `await` an `HttpClient` call, you have to convert it to a promise first. IE: `this.httpClient.post(url, data).toPromise();`

Comment: I updated the service, let me know if any question.

Comment: That isn't the service code. It's not clear that your `service` is of the `SwaggerService` type but we have no idea what your method in said service is doing.

Comment: The service code is too long. Sorry about it. And is it necessary to need service code? Because I saw a lot of similar questions without service still got answered.